# C# wpf linq and observerable collection: how to use as a filter with combobox

Tags: .net, wpf, linq, observablecollection

I'm not actually sure how to ask the question so here's what I'm doing:

I have a datacontext that im using via LINQ to SQL

```
linqDatabaseDataContext db = new linqDatabaseDataContext();
```

I have a combo box with a bunch of values that i use to populate a custom listbox using the combobox value as a filter by calling this method. i pass the string from the combobox into the method

```
private void PopulateList(string filter)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(filter);

            var holds =
                from a in db.Record_HoldDatas
                join techs in db.LUT_Employees on a.LabTech equals techs.ID
                join qaSups in db.LUT_Employees on a.QASupervisor equals qaSups.ID
                join prodSups in db.LUT_Employees on a.ProductionSupervisor equals prodSups.ID
                join flavors in db.LUT_Flavors on a.Flavor equals flavors.ID
                where a.HoldStatus == filter
                orderby a.HoldID descending
                select new
                {
                    a,
                    QASupervisor = qaSups.firstName + " " + qaSups.lastName,
                    ProdSupervisor = prodSups.firstName + " " + prodSups.lastName,
                    Tech = techs.firstName + " " + techs.lastName,
                    Headline = a.HoldID + " : " + a.Package + " " + flavors.flavor,
                    Flavor = flavors.flavor,
                    Status = a.HoldStatus
                };

            lbxHoldsList.ItemsSource = holds;
        }
```

I want it to happen on selecteditem change of course. I know theres a way to do it through binding of an observable collection, but im at a loss of how to do it, im pretty new. The datacontext is pretty specific on the structure which is why I used the implicit type. Would anyone be willing to sort of push me in the right direction here?

Comment: What is the exact question?  And that MessageBox is for debugging?

Comment: yeah the message box was just to check if the right string was being passed.I was fiddling with the selectionchanged event. Its currently passing the text of the previous selection. I'm just trying to have the listbox contents update when I select a different filter from a combobox. The filter obviously being a WHERE clause in a linq query. Right now, the query results are being bound to the itemssource of the listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MVVM:

Add a(n observable)collection of filters to the ViewModel, add a property to the ViewModel name SelectedFilter. Bind the SelectedFilter to the SelectedItem property of the ComboBox.

Add a handler in the ViewModel that is called when the SelectedFilter changes. In the handler call the Populate method.